# Using preg_replace and preserving part of search

Tags: php, regex

With preg_match, you can use `<name>` and it will add that to the output array.

With preg_replace, I'd like to match a url, such as `"http://<url>\s"` and then have that url preserved in the replacement string, such as `"beforetheurl<url>aftertheurl"`

Comment: Use $1 in the replacement string in the position where you want it. $n holds the result of the nth matching group, $0 holds the entire matching result. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to my comment:

```
<?php

$result = preg_replace("/(matched)/", 'before$1after', "matched");

echo $result;
```

Output: `beforematchedafter`

http://codepad.org/PANzOm6c

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I'll choose your answer once the waiting limit is up since you were technically first to answer my question correctly (I understood from your comment).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [back reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) in the replacement string.

```
echo preg_replace('#http://(\w+).*$#', 'sld = $1', 'http://mysite.com');

// output: sld = mysite
```

More from the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> replacement may contain references of the form \n or (since PHP
>   4.0.4) $n, with the latter form being the preferred one. Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th
>   parenthesized pattern. n can be from 0 to 99, and \0 or $0 refers to
>   the text matched by the whole pattern. Opening parentheses are counted
>   from left to right (starting from 1) to obtain the number of the
>   capturing subpattern. To use backslash in replacement, it must be
>   doubled ("\\" PHP string).